# Reveal hide view in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uikit

My app is hearing for some audio watermarks and it works fine. Now I wanted to make this app much pretty by using an hide view in which I put a label and a button. I draw a view in Storyboard, then I put this view at the top of view controller (exactly at position x = 0 and y = -200). Now I need to show this view when the phone hears a watermark (to recognize watermarks I used [Pitch detector](https://github.com/irtemed88/PitchDetector)).
I wrote the following code to recognize frequency of the signal:

```
- (void)frequencyChangedWithValue:(float)newFrequency {
    frequencyRecived = newFrequency;
    watermarkReceived = YES;

    NSLog(@"%f", frequencyRecived);

    if (frequencyRecived > 18000) {
        if (frequencyRecived >= 18000 && frequencyRecived <= 18140 && !water1) {
            [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(setTextInLabel:) withObject:@"1"];
            water2 = water3 = water4 = NO;
            water1 = YES;
        }
        if (frequencyRecived >= 18150 && frequencyRecived <= 18290 && !water2) {
            [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(setTextInLabel:) withObject:@"2"];
            water1 = water3 = water4 = NO;
            water2 = YES;
        }
        if (frequencyRecived >= 18300 && frequencyRecived <= 18440 && !water3) {
            [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(setTextInLabel:) withObject:@"3"];
            water1 = water2 = water4 = NO;
            water3 = YES;
        }
        if (frequencyRecived >= 18450 && !water4) {
            [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(setTextInLabel:) withObject:@"4"];
            water1 = water2 = water3 = NO;
            water4 = YES;
        }
    } else {
        [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(redLed) withObject:nil];
    }
}
```

and the selects are the following:

```
- (void)redLed {
    [self.imageLed setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image_led_red.png"]];
    self.labelPosition.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"DBLCDTempBlack" size:20.0];
}

- (void)setTextInLabel:(NSString*)position {
    self.labelPosition.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"DBLCDTempBlack" size:20.0];
    self.labelPosition.text = position;
    self.labelPositionHiddenView.text = position;
    NSString *textForToast = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Postazione %@", position];
    [self.view makeToast:textForToast duration:3.0 position:@"bottom"];
    [self.imageLed setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image_led_green.png"]];
}
```

The selector `setTextInLabel` is called when the device recognize a frequency so I updated the selector so:

```
- (void)setTextInLabel:(NSString*)position {
    self.labelPosition.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"DBLCDTempBlack" size:20.0];
    self.labelPosition.text = position;
    self.labelPositionHiddenView.text = position;
    // Instructions to recall my hide view
    [UIView transitionWithView:self.view
                      duration:0.5
                       options:UIViewAnimationOptionAllowAnimatedContent
                    animations:^{
                        [self.viewHidden setFrame:CGRectOffset(self.viewHidden.frame, 0, 340)];
                    }
                    completion:nil];
    //-----------------------------
    NSString *textForToast = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Postazione %@", position];
    [self.view makeToast:textForToast duration:3.0 position:@"bottom"];
    [self.imageLed setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image_led_green.png"]];
}
```

When I try to run the app and the device hears the watermark it recognize it, it calls the selector `setTextInLabel`, but it doesn't execute the code to recall the view. I don't understand why's that, I hope you can help me to fix this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is because you're calling `performSelectorInBackground:`, and those methods you're invoking in the background are making changes to UIKit elements. All changes to UIKit elements need to be done on the main thread. So both `redLed` and `setTextInLabel:` need to be executed on the main thread, not a background thread.

The exact behavior of calling UIKit methods from off the main thread is technically undefined. From what I have seen, doing this sometimes results in the UI elements never getting updated. In some other cases, they do get updated, but only after a long delay or after the UI element has had some other change made to it that forces it to refresh its state. I think you're seeing a situation where it just never does the thing you want it to do, probably because you tried to do an animation from another thread, which most likely never works.

Comment: I can't execute in main thread because if I execute this code in the main thread it will block the phone and the app will crash...

Comment: @lucgian841 You need your `frequencyChangedWithValue:` method to execute in a background thread, and perform your UI updates on the main thread. Your UI updates shouldn't take so long that they would block.

Comment: @lucgian841 What thread is `frequencyChangedWithValue:` running on right now?